# Escaping a # symbol in a #define macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Without going into the gory details I want to use a `#define` macro that will expand to a `#include` but the '#' sign is confusing the preprocessor (as it thinks I want to quote an argument.)

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
#define MACRO(name) #include "name##foo"
```

And use it thus:

```
MACRO(Test)
```

Which will expand to:

```
#include "Testfoo"
```

The humble # sign is causing the preprocessor to barf.  MinGW gives me the following error:

`'#' is not followed by a macro parameter`

I guess I need to escape the # sign but I don't if this is even possible.

Yes, macros are indeed evil...

Comment: You cant do that! The macro processor is rather primitive.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As far as I remember you cannot use another preprocessor directive in define.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a better way to achieve what I was after in the end, without using macros.

Comment: It would have been nice if you mentioned in which way you achieved what you wanted? :-)

Answer (score 43):

It *is* possible to insert a hash token into the preprocessed token stream. You can do it as follows:

```
#define MACRO(hash, name) hash include name
MACRO(#,"hello")
```

—expands to:

```
# include "hello"
```

*However*, the standard explicitly rules out any further analysis of such line for the existence of preprocessing directives [cpp.rescan]:

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one.

Answer (score 32):

The problem isn't actually getting a # symbol in the output of your preprocessor.

Apparently you want the preprocessor to reparse your file, to deal with newly created #include directives as part of macro expansion. It doesn't work that way. If a line starts with #, it's an instruction for the preprocessor and interpreted. If a line doesn't start with #, it's only subject to preprocessor transformation including macro substitution. This is a once-per-line test.

```
MACRO(Test)
```

does not start with #. Therefore it is not interpreted as a preprocessor directive; instead it's subject to macro replacement rules.

Comment: Clearest answer on here I think - effectively he's asking for a 2nd parse of the preprocessor, well noted.

Answer (score 12):

This is because the # has special meaning when used in a macro.

```
#  means quote the following token (which should be a macro parameter name)
## means concatenate the preceding and following tokens.
```

In your situation the # is not followed by a proper token.
So in your situation we need to go through a level of indirection:

```
#define     QUOTE(name)     #name
#define     TEST(name)      QUOTE(name ## foo)

#include TEST(scot)
```

Comment: This works for the question, where the name to be included doesn't need `.h` appended.  It is harder to make it work in a scenario where you have `#include USR_HEADER(name)` in the code, and you want it to become `#include "name.h"` for C or `#include "cname"` for C++.  That's because token pasting doesn't work when one of the tokens is `.h` and because string concatenation occurs after the preprocessor is finished (so generating `#include "name" ".h"` leaves you with an invalid preprocessor directive).  I'm not yet sure how to solve that, or `STD_HEADER(stdio)` for `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that.  Preprocessor directives are recognized before macro expansion; if the macro expands into something that looks like a preprocessor directive, that directive will not be recognized.  The best you can do is create a macro for the file name:

```
#define MACRO(name) "name##foo"
...
#include MACRO(Test)
```

Comment: Note that a modern preprocessor won't expand the `name` inside the quotes; this will end up as `#include "name##foo"` regardless of the value passed to the macro.

Comment: You can use also `#define MACRO(name) #name "foo"` that simply rely on string concatenation done when 2 strings are following on a single statement.

Comment: @xryl669: Note that adjacent string literal concatenation is done in Phase 6 of the translation process, but the preprocessor finishes in Phase 4.  Thus, the `#define MACRO(name) #name "foo"` won't help; it will generate two separate strings which is not a valid header name.

Answer (score 2):

This *might* work (it works for regular `#define` macros with no parameters, but I haven't tested it with macros with parameters).

```
#define MACRO(name) <name##foo>
#include MACRO(Test)
```

Comment: Use `<>` instead of `""`. `""` Are not interpolated.

Comment: that will not allow for the case when you want to replace it with two #includes, or perhaps eliminate them altogether. But it's perhaps the best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define HASH_SIGN #
BOOST_PP_CAT(HASH_SIGN, include)
```

Comment: But the output of this is not a `#include` directive (it is just a line that contains `#include`); you can't generate preprocessor directives like that.  You also haven't really explained what `BOOST_PP_CAT` is and where you get it from.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To be fair, if you google `BOOST_PP_CAT` you find only information on the macro that he meant. And the name is long enough to consider this a GUID ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define PARAM_NAME Param
#define GETNAME_(a) #a
#define GETNAME(a) GETNAME_(a)

int Param;
printf("%s = %i\n", GETNAME(PARAM_NAME), PARAM_NAME);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be related to the question, which is really asking about how to generate a file name for use with `#include`.