# How can I secure the plugins I load?

Tags: c, security, plugins, shared-libraries

Let's say my piece of code scans the directory `./plugins` and loads `.dll`s/`.so`s with a known symbol ("function" here) in order to extend its functionnality, like this:

> main.c
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <dirent.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <dlfcn.h>
>
> int
> main(void)
> {
>     DIR *dir;
>     struct dirent *entry;
>     dir = opendir("./plugins");
>     if (dir == NULL)
>         return -1;
>     while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
>     {
>         void *handle;
>         char path[PATH_MAX];
>         int (*function)(char *);
>         if (strstr(entry->d_name, ".so") == NULL)
>             continue;
>         if (snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "./%s", entry->d_name) >= sizeof(path))
>             continue;
>         handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_LAZY);
>         if (handle == NULL)
>             continue; // Better: report the error with `dlerror()'
>         function = (int (*)(char *)) dlsym(handle, "function");
>         if (function != NULL)
>             fprintf(stdout, "function: %d\n", function("example"));
>         else
>             fprintf(stderr, "symbol-not-found: %s\n", entry->d_name);
>         dlclose(handle);
>     }
>     closedir(dir);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

This could lead to a major security issue : If my application runs as root, or has admin privileges, that means any unprivileged attacker can execute code as a privileged user by producing a shared object containing a function named as the known symbol (here, `function`).

**What can I do to secure my `plugins` folder? How can I check if the shared objects I load are secure?**

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700873).

Comment: Could you explain why do you care about plugins security?

Comment: It is a general concern. Security should be in mind of every software developper, be it security of its application or of the whole system. Here, the whole system can be compromised by an attacker because of my code.

Comment: But why don't you trust the plugin?

Comment: Because anyone could have put it in the folder, including a malicious attacker.

Comment: Then your entire approach is wrong.

Comment: Send me an email with the URL of your question if you want more. We might even talk on the phone (if you give me some number to call) in French

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you cannot secure your plugin in the general case. A malicious user could do *arbitrary things* in its plugin (including emitting some C code at runtime then forking a compilation of it and `dlopen`-ing, JIT compiling machine code in memory, etc...). Remember that `dlopen`-ed  (or `mmap`-ed) plugins are sharing the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running their loading program.

<sup>My [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) [meta-] plugin for the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is doing exactly that: generating C or C++ code at runtime, compiling it on the fly, `dlopen`-ing it. But it is not malicious.</sup>

Notice that (as [answered by Art](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722595/841108)), [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is running arbitrary initialization plugin code (*before* you do any `dlsym` to retrieve a function from its `"function"` name). Read about [`__attribute__((constructor))` in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html).

If you are *extremely ambitious* (years of work, worth a PhD...) you might generate the code of the plugin while doing some code proof or sound [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) on it.

<sup>(Since you are like me near Paris, France, look into the works of Xavier Leroy -INRIA- e.g. [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/), Emmanuel Chailloux -LIP6-, Julia Lavall & [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) -LIP6-; read also about [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) & [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); but understand that **there is [no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet)**....; you could send me an email mentioning the URL of your question)</sup>

Read also about the **[halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem), [trusted computing base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base) and [proof-carrying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-carrying_code)**. **Your request is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)** or at least [intractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability).

You could consider some dual approach: have a *trusted* procedure to "sign" or "stamp" good plugins (so the sysadmin is in charge of telling that such and such plugin is good), and only `dlopen` a plugin when it has been "certified" or simply "human-approved" somehow. Perhaps as simple as keeping a (trusted and safe) database or text association between trusted plugin names and their md5 signatures, and computing the checksum then checking that before the `dlopen` ...

<sup>A good heuristic when programming is to ask very often to oneself: Am I trying to solve the halting problem? [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) has interesting insights....</sup>

Comment: does it means every single call to `dlopen()` can lead to a security issue ?!

Comment: Yes, of course. Actually, having any kind of function pointer is already a security issue

Comment: As a side note, verifying that the directory containing the plugins is owned by a trusted user and group and is not world-writable, and that the plugin file is also owned by a trusted user and group, not world-writable, and has exactly one hard link, before opening it, usually suffices. It is still suspect to a race wrt. renaming a parent directory (although you can try to mitigate that by checking all parent directories, too). Most applications (e.g. Apache) use a fixed trusted (or "system") directory in lieu of those checks, though.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do in this case is to only allow a privileged user to write files in the plugin directory.

The moment you call `dlopen` on an unknown file you have already lost. Notice that you don't even need to call a function from it, a call to `dlopen` is enough since the shared object can have constructors that will be run automatically wether you want it or not.

You can't check if the shared objects are secure. To do that would be equivalent to solving the halting problem.