# paste operator in macros

Tags: c, macros

I found the following snippet of code .

```
#define f(g,g2) g##g2
main() {

    int var12=100;
    printf("%d",f(var,12));

}
```

I understand that this will translate f(var,12) into var12 .

My question is in the macro definition, why didn't they just write the following :

```
#define f(g,g2) gg2
```

why do we need ## to concatenate text, rather than concatenate it ourselves ?

Comment: You can try it yourself. If you're using gcc or clang, compile with `-E` and  look at the output of the preprocessor.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) ? BTW, in some cases, you can generate C code (e.g. with the [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) preprocessor)

Comment: @Basile: Yikes.  Maybe point the OP to the specific part of that tome that pertains?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: what does "yikes" mean? The best dictionnary I have don't mention it (and I am a native French)

Comment: It means the OP probably doesn't need the whole Bible, just a chapter or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one writes `gg2` the preprocessor will perceive that as a single token. The preprocessor cannot understand that that is the concatenation of `g` and `g2`.

Comment: Are you saying that `##` is not an escaped `#` here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, a single hash is the stringification operator. A double hash is the concatenation operator. They are two entirely different operators. Much the same way that `-x` and `--x` mean two entirely different things.

Comment: So escaping a hash is a context-sensitive operation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know what language you're thinking about. There is no method to escape a hash in the C preprocessor (except by hacks and misdirection). See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244660/how-to-escape-a-in-a-macro).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    #define f(g,g2) g##g2
> ```

**My opinion is that this is poor unreadable code**. It needs at least a comment (giving some motivation, explanation, etc...), and a short name like `f` is meaningless.

> My question is in the macro definition, why didn't they just write the following :

> ```
> #define f(g,g2) gg2
> ```

With such a macro definition, `f(x,y)` would still be expanded to the token `gg2`, even if the author wanted the expansion to be `xy`

Please take time to read e.g. the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) (and of your compiler, perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and later some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better.

Consider also designing your software by (in some cases) generating C code (inspired by [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)). Your build machinery (e.g. your `Makefile` for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) would process that as you want. In some cases (e.g. programs running for hours of CPU time), you might consider doing some [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) and generating specialized code at runtime (for example, with [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)). Pitrat's book on [*Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) explains and arguments that idea in an entire book.

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (e.g. with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and learn to use a debugger (like [GNU gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

On Linux systems I sometimes like to generate some (more or less temporary) C code at runtime (from some kind of [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)), then compile that code as a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), and [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that plugin then [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) inside it. For a stupid example, see my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program (to demonstrate that you can generate hundreds of thousands of C files and plugins in the same program). For serious examples, read books.

You might also read books about [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) or about [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)); both have a much richer [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)) system than C provides.

Comment: I looked at N1570, and it's nearly eight hundred pages long.   Does the OP really need to know all of that to suss out `##`?

Comment: I guess the OP could buy a shorter book about C programming. My recommendation is to go to some university and follow courses about C programming - human teachers are often better than just reading books