# define without a # in front of it in C

Tags: c, syntax

What does "define" in C code without a # in front of it mean?  For example, what's the difference between these two lines:

```
define retadd "\x9f\x45\x3a\x77"
#define port 110
```

I found this in code found here:
https://www.exploit-db.com/raw/643/

Comment: I'd call that a bug in the code.

Comment: It is **clearly** a typo. If you look at the use, it would work if you just `#define`d it like everything else

Comment: Or, rather, it is a security feature, so that non-c-savvy people couldn't readily use the exploit.

Comment: Could it be already 'defined' like #define define #define ?  Just a thought...But i agree that its probably a typo

Comment: @Grantly: No, you can't do that. The `#` operator stringifies its arguments, and it's only usable in function-like macros.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not standard C: that’s for sure.

It might be something very compiler specific or a bug in the source code.

Comment: Just to expand on what you said: I wondered, "Perhaps you could define a preprocessor macro without `#`, and this is what happened above?" but the answer to that is no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289287/1462295

Answer (score 0):

`define` without a leading `#` is just another identifier, and in that context would be a syntax error (it's not a declaration specifier or type name, which is what the compiler expects at that point).  That code must be a typo.